# Gradle: Failed to create directory while building jar

Tags: java, build, gradle

I have a multi project gradle build, (Gradle version 1.9).

I am running `gradle clean build distZip` from `/vagrant` directory. `/vagrant` is the root project directory. This directory contains another directory `my-app`. While executing `jar` task, I see the following error:

```
Failed to create parent directory '/my-app' when creating directory '/my-app/build/tmp/jar'
```

Why is the jar task trying to create `my-app` under the root directory? It is not getting permission for that. Shouldn't it create under `./my-app/build/tmp/jar`?

Edit: Add settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'my-app'
includeFlat 'my-app-core', 'my-app'
```

Comment: Most likely due to a bug in one of the build scripts. The `build` in `my-app/build` is the build output directory for the `my-app` project, not the root project directory. (It would be preferable not to name the latter `build` in order to avoid confusion.)

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Is there a work around for this?

Comment: The solution is to fix the build. But without detailed information about the build, it's impossible to say from a distance what the problem is.

Comment: can you post your gradle settings  file?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Sorry I read it wrongly as bug in gradle. But I did not gather from you comment, as why `/my-app/build` is created instead of `./my-app/build`?

Comment: Most likely because some build script mistakenly uses an absolute path somewhere. `settings.gradle` is a candidate, as are all `build.gradle` scripts.

Comment: @vkg Added settings.gradle content

Comment: Try replacing includeFlat with just include

Comment: `includeFlat` (rather than `include`) mandates that child projects should be *siblings* of parent projects in the directory hierarchy. Therefore, it's expected that the project directory for `my-app` will be `/my-app`.

Comment: @Prasanna did replacing includeFlat with include worked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing **"includeFlat"** in settings.gradle file with **"include"** it will work :)